# How to detect taps on CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

Well I have made a `UIView` subclass. Inside it a have placed a `UIScrollView` object that has a circular shape and contains a uiviewimage. I have also placed `CAShapeLayer` that has a circular shape. the `CAShapeLayer` is above the `UIScrollView` and is overlapping a little. I want to be able to detect tap when I touch the `CAShapeLayer` and still be able to scroll inside the `UIScrollView` when I want. The problem is some area of the `CAShapeLayer` can not detect tap, but I want to detect the whole object even though it place above the `UIScrollView` because it is overlapping a little on the right side.

For better understanding please look at this picture: [image]

The problem is I don't know how to fix that, please show me with code how to do that...

Comment: Layers don't detect events; they aren't UIResponders.  I think you'll need to create a UIView subclass that uses a CAShapeLayer as its layer class.  You can find numerous examples and tutorials via your favorite search engine.

Comment: can you point me to some code to try out??

Comment: if you want i can even pay you

Comment: https://maniacdev.com/2013/08/uiview-subclass-backed-by-cashapelayer-that-makes-creating-custom-shapes-and-animations-easier

Answer (score 0):

You can add tap gesture recognizer on view containing the layer and then detect if layer's frame contains the tap point